# Fine grained locking

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, mutex

Let's say we have a big array and many threads operating on concrete indexes in that array. Two threads cannot operate on one index at the same time, one should wait until the other finishes. And the lame question: How to implement `test-and-set` locking on each index of the array in Linux/C/C++?

Comment: How about using a struct as your array element, so each element has the data and some bits used for locking?

Comment: That might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144349/boost-threads-mutex-array

Answer (score 5):

For fine grained locking, use an array of read/write locks (as Carey Hickling suggests). Hash the index value and filter it through a bit mask (or use modulus) to select which lock to use.

This effectively splits the indexes into N buckets, where N is the number of locks you create. Choose a power of two for the number of locks for easy bit masking (mask = N - 1). The only drawback in this scenario is that you're not just locking a specific index, you're locking every index that, when hashed, aligns to the same lock pointer.

That being said, the more locks you create, the finer grained the locking is (16 is probably a good starting point). Read locks are shared with rw_locks as well, so you only have to worry about waiting for the lock during writes.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant solution, I come here with the idea that I would have to use either just one lock for the array which would limit parallelism or one mutex per element, which could be an enormous amount of locks. Thanks!

Comment: Is there and easy way to map into a few buckets? Would you use `std::hash` modulo `%16` for example?

Answer (score 3):

You either need a simple mutex and do:

```
    mutex.lock();
    //access array using index
    mutex.unlock();
```

Or POSIX provides a read write lock. You can therefore do:

```
    pthread_rwlock_rdlock(rw_lock_ptr);
    // read the array
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(rw_lock_ptr);
```

And:

```
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(rw_lock_ptr);
    // update the array
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(rw_lock_ptr);
```

This allows shared locks for read operations and exclusive locks for write operations.

I would suggest that you have a class or pair for each element of the array and implement one of the above. If you hide the mutex locking in read/update functions of the class then you can, more easily limit the scope of mutex locks and easily avoid deadlocks.

Answer (score 2):

Make the array element type into something synchronized. If you want to mutex your data, you could have a `std::pair<T, std::mutex>`; if you can get away with a spinlock on each access, you could have a `std::pair<T, std::atomic<bool>>`. Then just let each array access acquire exclusive access to the element by means of the synchronization datum.